# TypeScript error in an onSubmit assignment in TSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, tsx

I created an interface ILogin with 'email' and 'password':

```
export interface ILogin {
    email: string
    password: string
}
```

Here is the code where I use it:

```
interface ILoginProps {
  login: (a: ILogin) => void
}

class Login extends React.Component<ILoginProps> {
    public render() {
        const { login } = this.props
        return(
          <Container center={true}>
            <Card>
              <Title>Log In</Title>
              <LoginForm onSubmit={login} /> 
            </Card>
          </Container>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => state
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  login: (payload: any) => dispatch(loginThunk(payload))
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

LoginForm code, I'm using InjectedFormProps from redux-form:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {reduxForm, InjectedFormProps, Field} from 'redux-form';

class LoginForm extends React.Component<InjectedFormProps> {
    public render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props
        return(
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Field label='Mail' name='email' type='email' placeholder='Mail' component={Input} />
                <Field label='Password' name='password' type='password' placeholder='Password' component={Input} />
                <Button block={true}>Confirm</Button>
                <Center>
                <Link to='/register'>Register</Link>
                </Center>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'login',
})(LoginForm)
```

And I get this error because seems like is not assignable in onSubmit:

```
TypeScript error in ****:
Type '(a: ILogin) => void' is not assignable to type 'FormSubmitHandler<{}, {}, string> | SubmitHandler<{}, {}, string> | undefined'.
  Type '(a: ILogin) => void' is not assignable to type 'FormSubmitHandler<{}, {}, string>'.
    Types of parameters 'a' and 'values' are incompatible.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ILogin': email, password  TS2322

    20 |             <Card>
    21 |               <Title>Log In</Title>
  > 22 |               <LoginForm onSubmit={login} />
       |                          ^
    23 |             </Card>
    24 |           </Container>
    25 |         )
```

Comment: What do the props for `LoginForm` look like?

Comment: Use **interface ILoginProps { login: any }**, or change **<LoginForm onSubmit={() => login(...)} />**

Comment: @Wex there, i add the code in the post. Thx.